# why my bundle can't be used if there's a "Contents" folder in it?

Tags: ios, xcode, macros, bundle

My bundle name is "sdk.bundle". I use this code to get a bundle:

```
NSBundle * bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sdk" ofType:@"bundle"]];
NSString * filePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"bg" ofType:@"png"];
```

The bundle has values. I can print the absolute path of the bundle. But the filePath is nil.This is the struct of my bundle:

```
SampleApp.app
   |----SampleApp
   |----Info.plist
   |----sdk.bundle
   |        |----Contents
   |        |        |----Resources
   |        |                 |----1.png
   |        |                 |----2.png
   |        |----bg.png
   |        |.....
   |......
```

When I remove the Contents folder, everything works well ! filePath has values. Can anybody give me some hits?

Answer (score 0):

Every app has a Contents folder inside. You can see this even on your mac, right click on an application and choose show package contents, you'll se a 'Contents' folder inside.

Comment: But why I can runs well if there's no Contents foldr inside ? Doen't it be some error ? By the way ,I edit the tree of struct of bundle above.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the NSBundle object for `pathForResource:`. This explicitly looks in the Contents/Resources folder of the bundle. However, it seems there's a fallback to just look in the root of the bundle.

I suspect this is because on OS X, bundles always have Contents folders. However, on iOS, they don't so if a Contents folder isn't there it just looks in the root folder.

> The method first looks for a matching resource file in the non-localized resource directory of the specified bundle. (In OS X, this directory is typically called Resources but in iOS, it is the main bundle directory.) If a matching resource file is not found, it then looks in the top level of any available language-specific “.lproj” directories. (The search order for the language-specific directories corresponds to the user’s preferences.) It does not recurse through other subdirectories at any of these locations.

[Source NSBundle docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000214-BCIBAHJF)

Comment: I has some confused. It says that the no-localized resource directory of iOS is main bundle directory. Is the main bundle directory the "SampleApp.app/" or "SampleApp.app/sdk.bundle/" or "SampleApp.app/sdk.bundle/Contents/Resources" ?

Comment: That depends on which bundle you're talking to. If you're sending `pathForResource:` to `[NSBundle mainBundle]`, it's "SampleApp.app/", but if you're sending it to `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sdk" ofType:@"bundle"]]`, it's "SampleApp.app/sdk.bundle/"